# Selenium junit problem - message: no such alert

Tags: java, html, selenium, junit

I am using selenium junit for my project. When I try to run my test, it return this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no such alert
```

It should return, after clicking a button, a confirmation alert and the user should press ok.

Test code:

```
  @Test
  public void adminDeleteDoc() {
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/login");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(550, 713));
    click(By.linkText("Accesso amministratori"));
    sendKeys(By.id("username"), "8245");
    sendKeys(By.id("password"), "prova1");
    click(By.id("submit"));
    click(By.id("btn_deletedoc"));
    assertThat(driver.switchTo().alert().getText(), is("Sei sicuro di voler cancellare questo dottore?"));
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
  }

    public void click(By locator) {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();
    }

    public void sendKeys(By locator, String text) {
        findElement(locator).sendKeys(text);
    }

    public WebElement findElement(By locator) {
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
    }
```

I tried also with webdriverwait (10), expected condition alert is present but it doesn't work.

Html code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div align="center">
            <h2>Gestione dottori</h2>
            <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-md">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Specialit&agrave</th>
                    <th>Azione</th>
                </tr>
                <tr th:each="doc: ${listDoc}">
                    <td th:text="${doc.getId()}"></td>
                    <td>Dr. <span th:text="${doc.getFirstName()}"></span> <span
                        th:text="${doc.getLastName()}"></span></td>
                    <td th:text="${doc.getDoc_type()}"></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="col col-md-auto align-self-center">
                            <div class="p-1">
                                <a th:href="@{/admin_deletedoc/{id}(id=${doc.getId})}" onclick="return confirm('Sei sicuro di voler cancellare questo dottore?');">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                                        id="btn_delete_doc" name="btn_delete_doc">
                                        <span id="btn_deletedoc" class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <a th:href="@{/admin_createdoc}"><span id="btn_createDoc"
                class="plus bg-dark">+</span></a>
            <hr>
            <div class="col col-lg-2 align-self-center">
                <div class="p-1">
                    <form th:action="@{/admin_logout}" method=post>
                        <button name="btn_logout_profile" id="btn_logout_profile"
                            type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log Out</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Where does that error occur? the second time you do `driver.switchTo().alert()`?

Comment: the first time i do assertThat(driver.switchTo...

Comment: As you answered here, the alert doesn't appear. At least Selenium doesn't see it. Do I understand you correct? And what do you mean by "I tried also with webdriverwait (10), expected condition alert is present but it doesn't work."? You see it visually, but Selenium doesn't recognize it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If I run my project it appears (also in selenium ide) but not in Selenium Junit. My guess was that the page wasn't fully loaded, so I put a webdriverwait for the alert but it fails (it gives me timeout exception).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the web page wasn't fully loaded before the click on the delete button.
So I put a thread.sleep of 1000 ms to resolve it.

Correct code:

```
@Test
  public void adminDeleteDoc() {
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/login");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(550, 713));
    click(By.linkText("Accesso amministratori"));
    sendKeys(By.id("username"), "8245");
    sendKeys(By.id("password"), "prova1");
    click(By.id("submit"));

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    click(By.id("btn_deletedoc"));
    assertThat(driver.switchTo().alert().getText(), is("Sei sicuro di voler cancellare questo dottore?"));
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
  }

    public void click(By locator) {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();
    }

    public void sendKeys(By locator, String text) {
        findElement(locator).sendKeys(text);
    }

    public WebElement findElement(By locator) {
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
    }
```

Comment: You should have a conditional wait, i.e. check until the page-title is available or something, and not just a fixed 1 second